# Django model designing problem when creating a follower / following relationship

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm trying to create a followig system for my application, and when I thought it worked, I realised that when account a started following account b, account b also started following account a

My models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='followers')
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='following')

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='p_author')
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    time = models.TextField() #Added when creating object with the API
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'author': self.author.username,
            'body': self.body,
            'time': self.time,
            'likes': self.likes
        }

class Comment(models.Model):
    post_commented = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='c_post')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='c_author')
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    time = models.TextField() #Added when creating object with the API
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The view that handles the follow action (called via a JS fetch call):

```
ef follow(request, profile_name):
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=profile_name)
    
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        print(request.user)
        data = json.loads(request.body)

        if data.get('follow') == True:
            followers_set = user_object.followers
            followers_set.add(request.user)
            user_object.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, status=204)
```

I'm supposing that I will need to restructure my whole database and project to fix this bug, how would you suggest I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding symmetrical=False on both user model attributes worked, Django, by defauld has a symmetrical relation on manytomany fields, as stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)